# How do I figure out how old my XBox Live account is?

Tags: xbox-network

Microsoft [announced](https://twitter.com/majornelson/status/268484136946253825) that the oldest Xbox live accounts get Xboxes, I don't think I qualify, but how do I determine how long I've been a member?

Comment: So, maybe I don't qualify for the promotion, because I haven't had xbox live gold this whole time, but I'm wondering how long I've had xbox live at all.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way to tell the age of your Xbox Live account is by viewing your [Gamercard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Live#Gamercard) from the Xbox Guide.

1. Boot your Xbox 360
2. Press the "Xbox" button in the center of the controller
3. Move all the way to the right and choose the "Profile" option
4. Look at the upper right hand corner of the screen - to the right of your gamertag there will be a number.  This is the number of years you've been an Xbox Live Gold member.  If you don't have a number, it hasn't been a year yet.

You can view this info on any of your friends' (or recent players') Xbox Live profiles as well.

As far as the 10th year anniversary promotion goes, they are sending these out to people who have been Gold members since the beta, so unless your number reads 10, you're unlikely to get one :)

The [sweepstakes](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Live/Anniversary), on the other hand, is open to everyone with Xbox Live.  Just download the gamer pic to enter.  Further, you can get a second entry if you're a member of Xbox Live Rewards, which is free and has other monetary benefits.

Comment: As a side note, all sweepstakes registration downloads are collated [here](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Xbox-LIVE-Event-Registrations/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802475207f5) - they sometimes change the URL, but you can find it under the A-Z games listing on the Xbox Dashboard, under "Xbox LIVE Event Registrations" typically.

Comment: This answer is slightly incorrect. The number will not show if your aren't a gold member. The number in istelf represents the total accumulated time you have been an XBL gold member, not the age of your account.

Comment: @Strike, ah, shoot.  I didn't make that clear, apologies.

Comment: Yes, I was able to find this information online, It's good, but not what I want, as I haven't had XBox Live Gold for as long.

Comment: @McKay, for the purposes of the promotion you're talking about in the question, this is the number they're going by.

Comment: @agent86 So, I think you might be right, but there's a strong distinction between "XBox Live" and "XBox Live Gold", and I would expect Major Nelson to know the difference. How do you know they're only looking for people with "10s"?

Comment: @McKay, Microsoft's been real cagey about the whole deal.  The only thing we have to go on are reports from people getting the boxes, like [this one on Kotaku](http://kotaku.com/5960013/microsoft-sending-xbox-live-veterans-a-custom-free-xbox-360?post=54231708).  [IGN's guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/xbox-360/How_to_See_If_You_Have_10_Year_Status) agrees with my assessment of account age.  One person said they also got [an email from Microsoft](http://www.the-nextlevel.com/tnl/threads/58058-This-Month-s-Haul-November-2012/page13) to confirm their address ahead of sending the box.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is sending e-mails out to "loyal members of Xbox LIVE."  I received one yesterday, and they may be still sending them out.

If you have an Xbox Live Gold Account, you can get look at your account billing history in the "My Account" section at http://live.xbox.com.

The entry to the contest is in the link below.  It is open to "eligible Xbox Live members", so it may give you an error if you have not been a member long enough:

http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Xbox-LIVE-is-10-sweepstakes/c047631c-eba3-4b60-98ee-15d2eaf24d22

To consider yourself eligible you will need to have had an active Xbox Live account on the first Xbox for at least 3 years before the release of the Xbox360, as the Xbox360 was released in 2005.

I've been unable to find anything in my account listing that just simply spells out how long it has been since I signed up.